# ActiveMQ long running python consumer processes stuck

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp

I have an ActiveMQ consumer written in Python's stomp.py library. These are long running consumers (e.g. 1 week). We have disabled the heartbeat(0,0). After some time (e.g. 20 hours) the consumers are getting stuck once they pick a message. We have written the consumer with reconnect mechanism that will reconnect once the connection failed, but still the consumers getting stuck.

**Logic:**

1. try to connect
2. is_connected() #true or false
3. if false -> got to step 1

**Environment details:**

1. Python 3.7
2. stomp.py 4.1.22
3. ActiveMQ 5.15.8 [network of brokers setup with active/standby{master/slave}]

**Python code:**

```py
import ssl
import stomp
LOG = custom_logger.get_logger("core")

class ActiveMQConsumer(ConsumerInterface):

    def __init__(self, service_conf):
        """
        Initialize the ActiveMQConsumer class that call create connection and adds listener.
        Args:
            service_conf : ActiveMQ configuration dict.
        Returns:
            None
        Raises:
            ConnectFailedException : Error while unable to connect to ActiveMQ
            Exception : Base exception to catch all other exception
        """
        try:
            LOG.verbose("Entry")
            self.username = service_conf["username"]
            self.password = service_conf["password"]
            self.hosts = service_conf["hosts"]
            self.ports = service_conf["ports"]
            self.callback = None
            self.subscription_details = {}
            self.heartbeats = service_conf.get("heartbeats", (0, 0))
            self.heart_beat_receive_scale = service_conf.get("heart_beat_receive_scale", 2.0)
            self.listener_obj = ConsumerListener(self)
            self.create_connection()

        except stomp.exception.ConnectFailedException as stomp_ex:
            raise stomp_ex
        except Exception as ex:
            raise ex

    def create_connection(self):
        """
        create connection with activemq brokers
        Args:
            None
        Returns:
            None
        Raises:
            Exception : Base exception to catch all exception
        """
        LOG.verbose("Entry")
        exclude_hosts = []
        for retry_count in range(MAX_CONNECTION_ATTEMPTS):
            try:
                selected_host, selected_port = select_host(self.hosts, self.ports,
                                                           exclude_hosts)
                conn_param = zip(selected_host, selected_port)
                self.conn = stomp.Connection11(conn_param, heartbeats=self.heartbeats,
                                               encoding=ENCODE_FORMAT,
                                               heart_beat_receive_scale=\
                                               self.heart_beat_receive_scale,
                                               reconnect_attempts_max=MAX_STOMP_RECONNECT_ATTEMPTS,
                                               reconnect_sleep_increase=RECONNECT_SLEEP_INCREASE)
                self.conn.set_ssl(for_hosts=list(zip(selected_host, selected_port)),
                                  ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
                self.conn.set_listener('connection_listener', self.listener_obj)
                self.conn.start()
                self.conn.connect(self.username, self.password, wait=True)
                LOG.info("Connected to activemq host :: "+str(selected_host))
                LOG.verbose("Exit")
                break
            except stomp.exception.ConnectFailedException as stomp_ex:
                LOG.info("retry fail count::"+str(retry_count))
                exclude_hosts.extend(selected_host)
                if len(exclude_hosts) == len(self.hosts):
                    exclude_hosts = []
                if (retry_count+1) == MAX_CONNECTION_ATTEMPTS:
                    LOG.verbose("Exit")
                    raise stomp_ex

    def __subscribe(self):
        """
        subscribes to queue in ActiveMQ broker
        Args:
            None
        Returns:
            None
        Raises:
            Exception : Base exception to catch all exception
        """
        try:
            LOG.verbose("Entry")
            subscription_id = 0
            for (destination, ack_mode) in self.subscription_details.items():
                self.conn.subscribe(destination=destination, id=subscription_id,
                                    ack=ACK_MODES[ack_mode],
                                    headers={"activemq.prefetchSize":1}
                                    )
                subscription_id += 1
            LOG.verbose("Exit")
        except Exception as ex:
            LOG.verbose("Exit")
            raise ex

    def consume(self, subscription_details, callback, **kwargs):
        """
        call subscription for activemq and provides connection failure retry with sleep.
        Args:
            subscriber_details : list contains queue names  with configuration(ack_mode).
            callback : callback function to send messages.
        Returns:
            None
        Raises:
            Exception : Base exception to catch all exception
        """
        try:
            LOG.verbose("Entry")
            self.callback = callback
            for (destination, config) in subscription_details.items():
                self.subscription_details[destination] = config.get("ack_mode", 2)
            while True:
                self.__subscribe()
                while self.conn.is_connected():
                    if os.getenv("CONTAINER_STOP", "FALSE") == "TRUE":
                        raise ContainerStoppedError()
                    #this loop holds the main thread till activemq connection available
                    time.sleep(CONSUMER_SLEEP_TIME)
                self.__reconnect()
        except Exception as ex:
            LOG.verbose("Exit")
            raise ex

    def __reconnect(self):
        """
        closes the inactive connection and creates the new connection with activemq.
        Args:
            None
        Returns:
            None
        Raises:
            None
        """
        LOG.verbose("Entry")
        reconnect_counter = 0
        while not self.conn.is_connected():
            try:
                self.close_connection()
                time.sleep(CONSUMER_RETRY_WAIT_TIME)
                self.create_connection()
                LOG.info("Connected to ActiveMQ...")
            except stomp.exception.StompException:
                reconnect_counter += 1
                LOG.info("reconnect failure count :: %s"%reconnect_counter)
        LOG.verbose("Exit")

    def close_connection(self):
        """
        closes the connection.
        Args:
            None
        Returns:
            None
        Raises:
            None
        """
        LOG.verbose("Entry")
        self.conn.disconnect()
        LOG.verbose("Exit")
```

Comment: Why would you disable heart-beating? It's especially important with long-running clients.

Comment: Heart beats used to make connection alive when there is no normal load. But some times messages are getting duplicated because of long processing messages. If so should I increase the heart beat time out @JustinBertram. Need  your thoughts on this sir. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Why specifically are messages being duplicated?

Comment: Hi @JustinBertram we have kept 15 secs as heartbeat interval. For some cases message processing time goes beyond 40 secs. Due to this reason these consumer are getting disconnected. Now we changed it to 60 secs. its working, thanks

Comment: Is it possible to embed this code in a Flask application and run it as a background thread? Python newbie here any link for the same would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

i think you should  disable heart-beating, and add on_disconnected for reconnect on your linstener!

Comment: We should not disable heart beating since these are long-running consumers. heart beat used to keep the connection alive.

Comment: We are using the `connection.is_connected()` method to check the connection status, it will return false when the connection lost.
That's how we are detecting the lost connections and reconnecting to ActiveMQ. Please let me know we have to include `on_disconnect` in the listener, will it provide any additional check which is not handled in the `is_connected()` method?